# Windows 10 does not start when Roccat keyboard and mouse are connected

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I cannot start Windows 10 Pro x64 with Roccat keyboard and mouse connected. In safe mode, Windows starts correctly. When I unplug the mouse or keyboard, Windows will start up.

I will add that it is a Lenovo y510p laptop. The laptop's bios is very limited. I only have these options in BIOS:

[![enter image description here][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQLJb.jpg)

<sup>Click for a larger version</sup>

I can't do much with this BIOS. In safe mode, the laptop boots normally but why?

Models: Roccat Vulcan Aimo 121, Roccat Kova

By "does not start", what I mean is that Windows won't start with Roccat's mouse and keyboard plugged in. It stays loading Windows with that spinning white circle

I found out what is the reason why windows do not start correctly. The problem is the sd card plugged into the laptop. When I remove the sd card, windows starts up properly

Comment: So start by updating UEFI. Then you may want to try disabling Fast Boot (UEFI setting).

Comment: What model are the roccat keyboard and mouse?

Comment: Change the boot order in the BIOS by putting your hard drive to the top of the boot list. It sounds like you have USB devices higher up in the boot order instead.

Comment: My keyboard: Roccat Vulcan Aimo 121 and mice: Roccat Kova @harrym

Comment: Please describe what “does not start” exactly means.

Comment: I cannot position the disk higher @Mastaxx

Comment: The latest [BIOS update V3.0827](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/downloads/ds100556-bios-update-for-windows-7-32-bit-64-bit-windows-8-32-bit-64-bit-windows-81-32-bit-64-bit-ideapad-y410p-y510p) is from 2015. Is that your version?

Comment: No my bios is V3.05 on V3.08 it's the same

Comment: @ All Keep in mind that if safe mode works, the boot sequence and everything is perfectly fine. // @nivenNo You might want to try the _Boot Log_ feature. It _might_ help you identify the problem.

Comment: I'd definitely look at how this keyboard/mouse is presenting over USB. Weirdness like non-contiguous interface numbers can screw up many implementations. Moreover, you can see if there is any Mass Storage in it to rule out the boot sequence hypothesis. The best would be to just hook it up to a hardware USB protocol analyzer to see what's going on. Barring that you can use https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#MicrosoftUSBView and copy the right pane.

Comment: It works in SM but I bet none of the fancy stuff works (if there's no fancy stuff why does it have drivers?). Driver issue? Something called "swarm". Reddit says they suck. https://www.reddit.com/r/Roccat/comments/uwro94/stay_away_from_vulcan_121_aimo/ ... Unless there's a virus trying to be sneaky it's not going to say "loading Windows" if there's a drive conflict and it can't boot. *W10 hangs when* is usually a third party's fault.

Comment: *"Often times I find it's software issues, SWARM crashing, not updating, hangs, lags, or visit another dimension."* https://www.reddit.com/r/Roccat/comments/hlf6r5/new_roccat_owner/

Comment: @Renate I edited my post. The SD card causes Windows to not start. When I remove the sd card, windows starts up properly

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution. Please write an answer to your own question. Don't forget to accept this answer when you can after 48 hours!

Answer (score 6):

These devices often have a little bit of storage onboard that the computer detects. This often pops up as a drive in explorer with drivers and settings placed on them.

If your windows is not set to boot from the Windows Bootloader, these drives may appear higher in the list.

All you need to do is enter the UEFI setup and set the bootloader to either Windows Bootloader or the harddisk windows is on incase windows bootloader is already the primary bootloader.

Comment: Often? More like “sometimes” (as in almost never). It’s _highly_ unlikely these would interfere with the boot order, even more so with EFI booting.